# Listening on raw sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, interface, raw-sockets

I am listening on a raw socket but I still don't get any ping packets. Here is my code

```
FD_ZERO(&interface_readfds);

sockfd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,
                        (char *)&sockopt, sizeof(sockopt));

strcpy(ifName, "vet1");

setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,
                        (char *)&sockopt, sizeof(sockopt));

max_sd = sockfd;
FD_SET(sockfd, &interface_readfds);

while(1){
retVal = select(max_sd + 1, &interface_readfds, NULL, NULL,
         &timeout);
if(retVal == 1){
/// I want to come here
  }
}
```

Here I dont get any result on select. It just times out. Any suggestions on what am i doing wrong ?

I am binding on ve1, and I do a ping on ve1p

```
 ping -I ve1p 1.1.1.1
```

So I should receive something on my code.

Comment: Try posting a complete MWE.

Comment: Can you post all code here?

Comment: Ping uses ICMP's Echo Request, which is control message number 8. Echo Replies use control message number 0. I don't see where you are setting any of this. Perhaps you should show more of your code. Or reference a real ping implementation: [ping filetype:c](https://www.google.com/search?q=ping+filetype%3Ac)

Comment: This is my entire code. I dont have anything else , can some1 tell me what to add